# image slider doesnt allow the dropdown of navbar in mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a conflict of events happening in my code.
I have a menu bar created using nav bar. There is a image slider namely the caroussel. The image is sliding, but when I minimize the window the menu bar does not drop down as it does without the caroussel.
I have my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap-3.3.4-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>

  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
             </button>
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.ab.com/">Welcome</a>   


    enter code here
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="http://www.ab.com/currentstudents">Current Students</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="http://www.ab.com/facultyandstaff">Faculty & Staff</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="http://www.ab.com/welcome/visiting/families1/">Parents & families</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="http://www.ab.com/alumni">Alumni</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="http://www.ab.com/welcome/visiting">Visitors</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="http://www.ab.com/academics/health-sciences-programs/clinics/"> Clinics</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="http://www.ab.com/give/">Support Us</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>

        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">

            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>   

            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="active item">
                    <img class ="frontimage" src="images/4yearplan_700.jpg" alt="mainpage">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <p>This is the first slide</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img class ="frontimage" src="images/alumni.jpg" alt="alumni">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <p>This is the second slide</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img class ="frontimage" src="images/better_air_photo3.jpg" alt="main">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <p>This is the third slide</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="jumbotron"> 
            <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
            <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
        </div>
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h3>Column 1</h3>
                 <p>This is column 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h3>Column 2</h3>
                <p>This is column 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h3>Column 3</h3>        
                <p>This is column 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `#myCarousel` (also move, `.jumbotron` and `.row` while you're at it) outside of the `.navbar-header` element.